# how to set all division to visible on top in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

this is my webpage code showing all the div tags as hide and with java script and making visible. while i am displaying div tags are having space ,I want to show visible div on the top .

```
<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" onclick="getIndex(this)">
    <asp:ListItem Text="one" Value="one"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="two" Value="two"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="three" Value="three"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    <div id="divone" style="display:none" >
    <iframe id="ifone" src="one.aspx" ></iframe>
        </div>  
    <div id="divtwo" style="display:none" >
    <iframe id="iftwo" src="two.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="divthree" style="display:none" >
    <iframe id="ifthree" src="three.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
    </div>
```

I am using Java script as

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function getIndex(r) {
         var rbs = r.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
         for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
             if (rbs[i].checked) {
                 var value = rbs[i].value;
                 debugger;
                 if (value == "one") {
                     hide();
                     document.getElementById('divone').style.display = "block";
                 }
                 if (value == "two") {
                     hide();
                     document.getElementById('divtwo').style.display = "block";
                 }
                 if (value == "three") {
                     hide();
                     document.getElementById('divthree').style.display = "block";
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     function hide() {
         document.getElementById('divone').style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById('divtwo').style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById('divthree').style.display = "none";
     }

</script>
```

Finally modified version i have placed. it is working now

Comment: I got the solution
Just doing visibility:hidden will keep the space that the div takes up.
So have to use style="display:none" and to show style="display:block"
I am editing the solution also with correct one

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution Just doing visibility:hidden will keep the space that the div takes up. So have to use style="display:none" and to show style="display:block"